# Setting Up A Html Page On A Server

Tags: html, css, web-hosting, file-management

I am trying to learn how to set up a html page on a server, which i have done but an index page appears, I do not want this page to appear i would rather my home page to appear.
[image: index page]

I am only learning how to do this so i have used a free web host. 
web address: http://testingmyfreewebsite.comxa.com/

My file manager looks like this [image: file manager]
[image]

The subPages and Css folders were created by me and they contain the css and other pages to my website. 
i would really like to know how to remove the index page i am open to many methods.

Comment: Rename `home.html` to `index.html`. Servers generally default to `index.*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three commonly used default page names that you can use on most web servers:

- index.html
- index.htm
- default.htm (on some Windows servers)

It's a good idea to stick with index.html or index.htm on most servers, as default.htm is most often used on Windows servers, and isn't as common as it used to be.

If you're going to put other pages inside of folders (or directories) each folder should have an index.html inside of it as well if you're relying on the url to direct the user instead of hard coding it in.

Comment: It can be more than .html and .htm. If you're using other languages, it can be .php or .asp, etc.

Comment: It _can_ be more than index `.html` or `.htm`, like `.php`, but that usually requires additional configuration after setting up a PHP processor (with Apache and Nginx, for example); most web servers don't support others out of the box.